# Fortran macro function for literal string?

Tags: macros, fortran

I have a sequence of subroutine calls I need to make on various datatype names. For example:

```
print*, 'Now giving information about Matrix1'
call mysub(Matrix1, size(Matrix1,1), size(Matrix1,2))
print*, 'About to do function on Matrix1'
call dofunction(Matrix1)
print*, 'Matrix1 is a nice matrix! Huzzah!'

print*, 'Now giving information about Matrix2'
call mysub(Matrix2, size(Matrix2,1), size(Matrix2,2))
print*, 'About to do function on Matrix2'
call dofunction(Matrix2)
print*, 'Matrix2 is a nice matrix! Huzzah!'

print*, 'Now giving information about OtherMat'
call mysub(OtherMat, size(OtherMat,1), size(OtherMat,2))
print*, 'About to do function on OtherMat'
call dofunction(OtherMat)
print*, 'OtherMat is a nice matrix! Huzzah!'
```

and I would like to define a macro that will take a `#define` value so that I can wrap this sequence of calls. For example, defining a macro `mymacro`, I would like to be able to call simply

```
mymacro(Matrix1)
mymacro(Matrix2)
mymacro(OtherMat)
```

to accomplish the same thing. Is this possible?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried googling for how to do this and come up with nothing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to get this working for `gfortran`, since it doesn't support [`#expr`](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2009-06/msg00131.html).

The idea is to use `;` to get multiple commands into one line. Of course, this requires to disable the usual line limit. With `gfortran`, this is achieved by `-ffree-line-length-0`.

Then, `gfortran`'s preprocessor uses `"x"` instead of `#s` (as every other compiler does). 
Here is the result: it is working on `ifort` and `gfortran`:

```
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__

#define mymacro(x) print *, "Now giving information about ", "x" ; \
                   call mysub( x, size(x,1), size(x,2) ) ; \
                   print *, "About to do function on ", "x"; \
                   call dofunction(x) ; \
                   print *, "x"," is a nice matrix! Huzzah!"

#else

#define mymacro(x) print *, "Now giving information about ", #x ; \
                   call mysub( x, size(x,1), size(x,2) ) ; \
                   print *, "About to do function on ", #x; \
                   call dofunction(x) ; \
                   print *, #x," is a nice matrix! Huzzah!"

#endif

program main

implicit none
integer :: i(2,2)

i = 123

mymacro(i)

contains

subroutine mysub(ii, N, M)
  integer,intent(in) :: ii(:,:), N, M
  print *,'in mysub:', ii(1,1)
end subroutine

subroutine dofunction(ii)
  integer,intent(in) :: ii(:,:)
  print *,'in dofunction:', ii(1,1)
end subroutine
end program main
```

Answer (score 2):

What about writing a subroutine like this:

```
subroutine mymacro(matrix, matrixName)
    ! declare matrix, precision should be declare somewhere as a constant
    real(precision), dimension(:,:) :: matrix
    character(*), intent(in) :: matrixname

    print*, 'Now giving information about '//matrixname
    call mysub(matrix, size(matrix,1), size(matrix,2))
    print*, 'About to do function on '//matrixname
    call dofunction(matrix)
    print*, matrixname//' is a nice matrix! Huzzah!'
end subroutine mymacro
```

It is not exactly the thing that will get the name of your matrix for you but close enough.

```
mymacro(matrix)
```

becomes

```
call mymacro(matrix,'matrix')
```

Not very different, don't you think?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this but I need a macro because the `size` is not being called correctly.

Comment: That problem of size is a little bit strange. What is happening exactly with the size?

Comment: I would rather not solve the problem of `size` right now as that will not answer the intent of my original question. I am looking for a preprocessor macro/directive.

Comment: As you wish! my curiosity can wait

Comment: I'd be happy to move this into a private chat, though I'm not sure how. If we keep commenting back and forth, SO will recommend it anyway!

Comment: It might be useful to note that the subroutine requires an explicit interface (such as by making it a module subroutine) because of the assumed shape dummy arguments - the absence of such an interface might be behind the OP's problem with `size`.  I would never recommend resorting to the preprocessor to do something as simple as this.

Comment: @IanH I am resorting to preprocessor directives to save on dev time. I am having to rewrite these lines ~50+ times and I want a simple command to copy/paste to do this instead of rewriting it each time. This will not be in the production code.

Answer (score 0):

Macros themselves are not part of Fortran. They are implemented by most (if not all) compilers by just reusing the C preprocessor. I learned from here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

This might do the trick: (not tested!)

```
#define MYSUB(m) write(*,*) "Now giving information about ", #m;  \
                 call mysub(m, size(m,1), size(m,2) ); \
                 write(*,*) "About to do function on ",#m; \
                 call dofunction(m) ; \
                 write(*,*) #m , "is a nice matrix! Huzzah!" ;
```

Note that you will have to use the appropriate compiler flags to have the compiler run the preprocessor.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work with `gfortran`, as it does not support `#m`. It took me quite a while to figure that out - see my answer below...